# Run mikogo on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I'm following instructions on Mikogo website http://www.mikogo.com/download/linux-download/, but it doesn't work. ./mikogo doing nothing. Please, help.

Comment: Have you extracted the mikogo.tar.gz archive?

Comment: did you change the mikogo file into an executable file by giving execute permission to that file?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Sure

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, its binary file. Does permissions matter if I make `sudo`?

Comment: Of course that the permissions matters, even if you use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikogo support helped me. From [Does Mikogo run with 64bit Linux? – Mikogo Help Desk](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707004444/https://mikogo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200453103-Does-Mikogo-run-with-64bit-Linux-):

> You have to install the 32bit libraries with the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```
>
> Starting with version 13.x, the `ia32-libs` can no longer be
>   installed. If you are using a 64bit Linux system with version 13 or
>   higher, please enter the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libidn11:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
> ```
>
> libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libxft2:i386
>
> followed by this command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
> ```

Comment: This is the reason why just providing link is useless. The link is now dead

Comment: I have found the information in the archive and edited your answer